# Rxjs multicast inconsistent error behavior in nodejs and browser

Tags: node.js, browser, rxjs, multicast

```
    const tick$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(10))
    const subject = new Subject<number>()
    tick$.subscribe(subject)

    subject
      .pipe(
        map(x => {
          if (x === 5) {
            throw new Error('error!!!')
          }
          return x
        })
      )
      .subscribe(x => console.log('x1: ', x))

    subject.subscribe(x => console.log('x2: ', x))
```

Above code run in browser, when `x === 5`, only `x1` is interrupted and `x2` can continue, but in nodejs, `x1` occured error killed the process. Somebody can explain why? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may need to catch the error

https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError

Answer (score 0):

in nodejs the process is killed when there is an error.
you should always do it like this:

```js
.subscribe(
  x => console.log('x1: ', x),
  err => console.error(err)
);
```